# Plotting incrementally increasing dates in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm wanting to plot the country vs a date range of exposures to COVID-19, as a learning tool in RStudio.

I've been trying to read the CSV and store as a dataframe, then plot via ggplot, but I think that I'm doing this incorrectly, since this is a date range.

How could I approach this to plot the infected countries to the dates, which increase daily in the header?

```
| Province/State | 1/21/2020 22:00 | 1/22/2020 12:00 | 1/23/2020 12:00 | 1/24/2020 0:00 |...
|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|----------------|
| Anhui          | 1               | 1               | 2               | 5              |...
| Beijing        | 1               | 1               | 3               | 4              |...
| Chongqing      | 2               | 4               | 5               | 6              |...
```

These cases are not accurate, just generated through MD to provide a table of data.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jeff, you will need to turn the data frame from wide to long. `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package makes this easy. Then you need to format the date column using `as.Date(var, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`.

Comment: I do that very thing with a version of those data in a Shiny app, the code for which you can find [on GitHub](https://github.com/ulfelder/practice-projects/blob/master/covid19/app.R). Take a look at the top of the "Data pulling and processing" section near the top of the script.

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I'm looking for!